# Rate of convergence $x_{n+1}=2\sin(x_n)$

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

$f(x)=\sin(x)-\frac{1}{2}x$ , for $x>0$

We are trying to evaluate the root of function using the following fixed-point iterative method:

$x_{n+1}=2\sin(x_n)$

What is the rate of convergence of the method?

Any direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should easily see that $x=0$ is an instable fixed point. Then also that $g([0,\pi])\subset[0,2]\subset[0,\pi]$ so that there is an attracting fixed point inside that interval.

Now you need to find better bounds for that point so that you can then compute a contraction factor as the maximum of the absolute value of the derivative. For instance, it is easy to see that $g([\frac\pi3,\frac{2\pi}3])=[\sqrt3,2]\subset [\frac\pi3,\frac{2\pi}3]$ and $2\cos([\frac\pi3,\frac{2\pi}3])\subset[-1,1]$, which is not sufficient but still closer.

---

Numerically you get 
$$
g([1.85, 1.95])\subset[1.85, 1.95]
~~\text{ with }~~
g'([1.85, 1.95])\subset[-0.75, -0.55]
$$ 
so that $\frac34$ is an upper bound for the convergence rate, $\frac12$ a lower bound.

---

One might get analytical results using 
$$
g(\tfrac\pi2+u)=2\cos(u)\in[2-u^2, 2-u^2+\tfrac1{12}u^4]\subset [2-u^2, 2-\tfrac{47}{48}u^2] ~~\text{ for }~~ u\in[0,\tfrac12].
$$

Comment: How do you prove there is an *attracting* fixed point?

Comment: How does it help me compute the rate of convergence?

Comment: @lhf : Because the orbits starting anywhere in $(0,\pi]$ have to end somewhere, and that "somewhere" can not be the point $0$. But to make that precise one needs the mentioned better bounds or smaller interval with a contraction constant to exclude the more exotic scenarios of limit cycles etc.

Comment: @UmShmum : You can only expect linear order of convergence. The contraction constant is an upper bound for the convergence rate. It is also a good approximation, if the bounding interval is sufficiently small.